# how do i segregate the data with given conditions?

Tags: sql, sas

Input data:

```
CUST    CHANNEL
A        ATM
B        POS
C        MOB
A        ATM
A        ATM
C        ATM
B        ATM
```

So i want that customers who only uses atm, that is A only.
OUTPUT DATA:

```
CUST     CHANNEL
A         ATM
A         ATM
A         ATM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the requirement correctly, you want a list of all customers who use `CHANNEL = ATM`, but none of the other channels.

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT
    CUST
FROM
    MyTable
WHERE 
    CHANNEL = 'ATM' 
    AND CUST NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT CUST FROM MyTable WHERE CHANNEL != 'ATM')
```

The subquery in the last line builds a subset of your table containing any customer using other channels. We exclude all those from the results in MyTable who did use `CHANNEL = ATM`.

*** Update following the comment it throws an error

I recreated the table, and ran the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable 
(
    CUST char(1)
    , CHANNEL char(3)
)
;

INSERT INTO myTable
VALUES ('A', 'ATM')
, ('B', 'POS')
, ('C', 'MOB')
, ('A', 'ATM')
, ('A', 'ATM')
, ('B', 'ATM')
, ('C', 'ATM')
;

SELECT
    CUST
    , CHANNEL
FROM
    MyTable
WHERE 
    CHANNEL = 'ATM' 
    AND CUST NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT CUST FROM MyTable WHERE CHANNEL != 'ATM')
```

This works without a hitch on SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks alot. Really helpful.

Comment: If this resolved your issue, please mark it as the accepted answer. That way future visitors to the question can see what did the trick for you. Thanks :)

Comment: You should accept the answer if it was what you were looking for.

Comment: there is a syntax error in the last statement where we exclude customers who used other than ATM.

Comment: SOLVED. I am sorry there was some minor glitch it seems.
Thank YOU.

Answer (score 0):

why not use a SAS SQL statement?

```
proc sql;
  Select * from input_data 
    where cust = 'A' 
    and channel = 'ATM';
quit;
```